# Custom Ribbon Button doesn't show on subsites

Tags: ribbon, custom-action

I've successfully added a custom ribbon button to my site and everything shows up as expected. However, when I go to a sub site, my custom ribbon button doesn't show up. How can I get my button to show up in the main site and also sub sites? I assumed that a button deployed to the main site would also carry over to sub sites but I guess that isn't the case. Anyone have any ideas or guidance? My button get's added to the "Media" group of the "Insert" tab for the RTE.

Here is my button code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Id="CommandUI.Ribbon.EditingTools.MyCompany_InsertVideoButton"
        Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
        <CommandUIExtension>
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIDefinition
                    Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.Controls._children">
                    <Button
                        Id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.Controls.MyCompany_InsertVideoButton"
                        ToolTipTitle="Video"
                        ToolTipDescription="Insert a video into the page."
                        Sequence="50"
                        LabelText="Insert Video"
                        Image16by16="/_layouts/MyCompany/images/icons/ribbonInsertVideoButton_16.png"
                        Image32by32="/_layouts/MyCompany/images/icons/ribbonInsertVideoButton_32.png"
                        Command="MyCompany_InsertVideoButtonCommand"
                        TemplateAlias="o1" />
                </CommandUIDefinition>
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
                <CommandUIHandler
                        Command="MyCompany_InsertVideoButtonCommand"
                        CommandAction="javascript:alert('MyCompanyInsertVideoButton clicked!');"
                />
            </CommandUIHandlers>
        </CommandUIExtension>
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did end up finally finding the problem to this, it wasn't actually a problem with any code anywhere, but it was a caching problem in the browser. Apparently, doing an F5 or ctrl-r refresh wasn't good enough to clear out the ribbon cache, so I had to manually clear out my browser cache, then I would see the correct ribbon. I feel like an idiot for this, but in any case it's something to note down for future users.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a Web-scoped feature. You should try to change your feature scope to `Site`.

Comment: Nope, it actually is a site scoped feature.

Comment: The behaviour described is certainly consistent with a web-scoped feature.

Comment: I'll test this as soon as I can.